# How do I get the keyboard rect if it's already displayed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a custom `UITextField` class which needs to grab the keyboard's rect after it's displayed. So, in the class I listen for `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and grab the keyboard's rect from `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`. This works great if the keyboard is not currently displayed. However, if the keyboard is already displayed -- such as when you tap between textfields -- `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` will only fire for the first textfield tapped. For every other textfield, I have no way of knowing what the keyboard's rect is.

Any suggestions on how I'd get the keyboard's rect *after it's already been displayed*?

Comment: Create a property for the rect, and set the value of that property when the keyboard first appears.

Answer (score 1):

Give your `AppDelegate` a `keyboardFrame` property.  Make the `AppDelegate` observe `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and update the property appropriately.  Set the property to `CGRectNull` when the keyboard is hidden, or add a separate `keyboardIsShowing` property.  (You can test for `CGRectNull` using the `CGRectIsNull` function.)

Then any object can check the keyboard frame at any time with this incantation:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate keyboardFrame]
```

If you don't want to put this into your app delegate, you can create a separate singleton class, e.g.

```
@interface KeyboardProxy

+ (KeyboardProxy *)sharedProxy;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CGRect frame;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL visible;

@end

@implementation KeyboardProxy

#pragma mark - Public API

+ (KeyboardProxy *)sharedProxy {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static KeyboardProxy *theProxy;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        theProxy = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return theProxy;
}

@synthesize frame = _frame;

- (BOOL)visible {
    return CGRectIsNull(self.frame);
}

#pragma mark - Implementation details

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _frame = CGRectNull;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    _frame = [note.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note {
    _frame = CGRectNull;
}

@end
```

But if you use a separate singleton, you need to be sure to call `[KeyboardProxy sharedProxy]` from your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` so that the singleton won't miss any notifications.

Comment: -1: the app delegate should only be used for initial setup. Instead, a singleton is better if you want a shared object.

Comment: The app delegate *is* a singleton.  Why bother creating another?

Comment: Note that you would have to initialize this other singleton before any other code has the chance to make the keyboard appear.  The app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is the appropriate place to do that.  So the app delegate needs to be involved anyway.

Comment: @JRG-Developer I agree with you. The delegate shouldn't be used for this type of thing. Although most devs do for convenience I avoid it if at all possible.

Comment: @robmayoff I agree it's a pretty nit-picky distinction whether you place the property in the `AppDelegate` or create a singleton that is initialized from the app delegate, but an important one, I think. It's not worth downvoting this answer though. +1.

Comment: @JRG-Developer The singleton is a good approach. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.